# CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null), Only with old records,why?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I have an app that actually have an version number of 2.4 .Starting from 1.0 version i have work with core data in app delegate in each update. So each update i have added elements to the original db that comes with version 1.0. This is the way a add an element for example:

```
 //ADD ELEMENT
if (context == nil) { context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; }
Negozi *newElement = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:context];
newElement.name=@"element name";
newElement.id=@"101";
[context save:nil];
```

The db that comes with 1.0 include newElement.id from 1 to 100 ,from newElement.id 101 are elements added in one of the newers versions of the app. The problems comes with deletObject. In this way i can delete an object from my context:

```
if (context == nil) { context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; }
NSError *error=nil;

///DELETE Element with id 101
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSString *ElementToDelete=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"101"];

for (int i=0; i<[fetchedObjects count]; i++) {

    if ([[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:ElementToDelete]) {

        [contesto deleteObject:[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i]];

    }
}

 [contesto save:nil];
```

With this code i can successfully deleteObjects from id 101 (the objects that are added with an update of the app). If i try to delete some elements with id<100 i obtain this error:

```
CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
```

this my managed object context code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Core Data stack


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

if (managedObjectContext_ != nil) {
    return managedObjectContext_;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    managedObjectContext_ = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext_ setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

}
return managedObjectContext_;
}



- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
    return managedObjectModel_;
}

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Elements" withExtension:@"momd"];
managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
return managedObjectModel_;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Elements.sqlite"];

NSString *storePath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Elements.sqlite"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Elements" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (defaultStorePath) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:defaultStorePath]];
    }
}



NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,

                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];



if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return persistentStoreCoordinator_;



}
```

Why i can't delete object stored initially in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through a list of fetch results and then want to modify it (by deleting an element). This can lead to the problem you are describing.

Instead, clean up your code and just fetch the element you want to delete, not all elements. This eliminates the loop and is also way more efficient.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:"Element"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", @(101)];
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
if (result.count == 1) {
    NSManagedObject *element = result.firstObject;
    [context deleteObject:element];
    [context save:&saveError];
}
else { NSLog(@"Element not found."); }
```